# How can I get started on prop making?

Tags: props

I want to get into prop making, mainly due to my encounter with a fully dressed and armed space marine.

I have searched the web on a tutorial for a bolter, for example, but only testimonials of a workshop's work comes up. Unfortunately I do not have the means or the experience for woodwork, so reinforced polysterine/foam with plastic or wood elements is about the limit.

From what I can tell, scifi props are the easiest because of the tendency for rectangular design, with fantasy (swords and such) being harder because of the shape.

Still I would want to start somewhere, but need some sort of clear guidance. So how do I start? :)

Comment: Is this in relation to playing pen and paper RPGs in anyway?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to make props & good resources for prop making vs. how to use props with regards to pen and paper RPGs.

Comment: This isn't on topic for our site; it falls outside our real-world topic guideline. An RPG expert isn't going to give you a better/different/more specific answer than an costume maker or cosplayer. Advice is going to be different depending on your needs, too: if you're cosplaying for show as a cosplayer, your needs are different to that of someone wearing such a costume for a LARP: in the latter, you're going to be performing strenuous activity for an extended period, and you're going to get hit with things. If this _is_ RPG-related, we need more detail on what you're going to do with this.

Comment: To clarify: if this is about table props, or LARP costuming, it is certainly on topic! But in that case we need more details because it's currently so *very* broad that good answers would be books.

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for our site. Which is too bad because there aren't any really good resources out there for large-scale props for RPGs (armor, weapons, magical items, space-marine suits, so on.) A great resource would be one part cosplay construction tutorials and one part theory (how to make table-worn props comfortable, what makes for good large props, what props have the biggest bang for their buck, how to make great prop sets for mysteries that all work together, so on)

Comment: No, it is not for larping, its for cosplay. Can you direct me to the proper stack exchange site to move this question?